# Passing parameters to a cli using exec in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-interface

I have the following situation.

I have a cli made in python in another folder and I have a function that receives some parameters and needs to be passed to the cli through an exec.

Estrutura de pastas
-execs
-fil1e.py
main.py

I tried to do it that way and it didn't work:

My main file

```
import sys

n = sys.argv [0]
stream = open ("execs / file1.py", n)
read_file = stream.read ()
exec(read_file)
```

Comment: Take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/how-to-execute-a-program-or-call-a-system-command-from-python?).

Comment: Thanx, It solved my problem!